# what are the changes to be made in order to convert tcp progrem into udp

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, udp, client-server

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<poll.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    struct pollfd fdarray[5];
    int sfd,port,nsfd,n,clen,ret,i;
    char buff[100];
    struct sockaddr_in sadd,cadd;
    memset(buff,0,sizeof(buff));
    sfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sfd<0)
    {
        printf("sorry unable to open the file");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(&sadd,0,sizeof(sadd));
    sadd.sin_port=htons(3503);
    sadd.sin_family=AF_INET;
    sadd.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    if(bind(sfd,(struct sockaddr*) &sadd,sizeof(sadd))<0)
    {
        printf("errortttt");
    //close(sfd);
        exit(0);
    }
    int r;
    r=listen(sfd,5);
    if(r<0)
    {
        perror("error");
    }
    memset(fdarray,0,sizeof(fdarray));
    fdarray[0].fd=sfd;
    fdarray[0].events=POLLIN;
    clen=sizeof(cadd);
    int rc,nfds=1;
    printf("waiting on poll\n");
    while(1){
        rc=poll(fdarray,nfds,-1);
        if(rc<0)
        {
            perror("poll failed");
        }
        int currentsize=nfds;
        for(i=0;i<currentsize;i++)  
        {
            if(fdarray[i].revents==0)
            continue;
        else if(fdarray[i].fd==sfd)
        {
            printf("socket is reading");
            nsfd=accept(sfd,NULL,NULL);
            printf("new connection is established");
            fdarray[nfds].fd=nsfd;
            fdarray[nfds].events=POLLIN;
            nfds++;

        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d",fdarray[i].fd);


            recv(fdarray[i].fd,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
            int j=0;
            for( j=1;j<nfds;j++)
            {
                if(j!=i)    
                send(fdarray[j].fd,buff,sizeof(buff),0);
        }
    }
}
}

return 0;
}
```

i am to new networking this is chat server which means than suppose there are 10 clients all are connected to the server when one of the client send a message the server should send the message to all the clients except the client which is sending  i done this using poll program written in  tcp what are the changes that are to made in order to convert into udp and how to poll in udp as there are no nsfds i.e mean accept call

```
#include "libsock"
int sfd=0;

* sender(void* dummy)
{
    char buf[512];
    int len=1;
    int i;
    while(len>0){
        for(i=0;i<512;i++)
        buf[i]='\0';
    fgets(buf,512,stdin);
    len=send(sfd,buf,strlen(buf)+1,0);
}
}

void* receiver(void* dummy)
{
    int len=1;
    char buf[512];
    int i;
    while(len>0)
    {
        for(i=0;i<512;i++)
        buf[i]='\0';
    len=recv(sfd,buf,512,0);
    printf("%s",buf);
}
}

int main()
{

    sfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sfd<0)
    {
        printf("socket error.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in serv;
    serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv.sin_port=htons(3503);
    inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&serv.sin_addr);
    if(connect(sfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv,sizeof(serv))<0)
    return 0;
    pthread_t s,r;
    pthread_create(&s,NULL,sender,NULL);
    pthread_create(&r,NULL,receiver,NULL);
    pthread_join(s,NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried. You can't dump two non-indented code listings and say "fix this", what is what this looks like.

Comment: About the same amount of changes to convert an accounting app into a game.

Comment: Indentation is required!

Comment: @CodeCaster i have done this b
int main()
{
struct sockaddr_in sadd,cadd;
int s,i,slen=sizeof(cadd);
char buf[1024];
int sfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
sadd.sin_family=AF_INET;
sadd.sin_port=htons(9000);
sadd.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
bind(sfd,(struct sockaddr*) &sadd ,sizeof(sadd));
//for(i=0;i<2;i++)
//{

while(1)
{

recvfrom(sfd,buf,1024,0,(struct sockaddr*)&cadd,&slen);
printf("received from from %s \n" ,buf);
char buf[100];
gets(buf);
if (sendto(sfd, buf, 1024, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&sadd, sizeof(sadd))==-1)
 printf("error");
printf("\n");
//}//
}
close(sfd);
return 0;
}

Comment: @CodeCaster i have done the simple server program but how to store nsfds in fdarray of poll without having accept in udp

Comment: @user1670364 You can see for yourself that posting non-trivial amount s of code in comments is a complete waste of time. It is utterly illegible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to send single packets without the usual guarantees TCP gives you then you can just change your programs into simple [**recvfrom**-client/server](http://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html) (*this part* is very similar for every OS), here's [more info](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom).

*BUT* if you want those guarantees, (1) that your packets arrive at all (2) in the correct order and (3) undamaged, then you will effectively have to re-implement TCP yourself. (This is sometimes done for games because they often dont care about old data) You will have to make both client and server re-send packages that were lost/damaged. So the packages have to be numbered and checksummed, but the tricky part is in deciding how long each of them should buffer data.

Comment: The tricky part is all of it, especially what you left out: windowing, slow start, exponential back off, RTT estimation, congestion avoidance, ...

Comment: @EJP absolutely, i only told the minimum because OP is new to networking.